# Finally, is PHP 5.4 Thread Safe?

Tags: php, thread-safety

The PHP community recently announced the release 5.4. So, here is my first question: Is this version finally thread safe?

I’ve read a lot of posts here and around on the Net about this hot topic (PHP tread safety) and I must admit that I’m a little bit confused.

As of today, my poor understanding on this subject is that the “thread safe” versions of PHP could be used on a multi threaded server such as Apache2-mpm-Worker (or IIS on Windows) when the none thread safe PHP versions should be used on a multi processes server such as Apache2-mpm-Prefork while it’s also my understanding that PHP by itself can’t start multiple threads.

I currently use PHP 5.3.10 on a Windows 7-64 system with WampServer2.2d-64 where phpinfo() states: Thread Safety : Enabled and Apache 2.2.21 Loaded modules: mod_php5 and also on another Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS (64 bit) system with PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14 where phpinfo() states Tread Safety: disabled and Apache 2.2.14 loaded Modules mod_php5. I thought using mod_php5 automatically loaded a thread safe version of PHP (but I guess I'm wrong).

So, here is my second question: Is PHP (any version) truly Thread Safe yes or no?

So my third question is: how to enable the thread safety option on my Ubuntu system?

And my last question on this subject is: is there a difference in execution times between the thread safe and non thread safe PHP/Apache versions?

PS: one additional question: How to install PHP 5.3.10 on Ubuntu since this package isn’t proposed by Synaptic?

Answer (score 1):

> Is any version / 5.4 finally thread safe?

A caveated Yes.  See the [obtaining PHP FAQ](http://hp.net/manual/en/faq.obtaining.php) and the [Windows download page](http://windows.php.net/download/).  Not all extensions are thread safe and bugs exist.  Most Linux distros supply the non-threaded version, including the Ubuntu ones.

> how to enable the thread safety option on my Ubuntu system.

You can get the packages `apache2-mpm-worker` and `apache2-threaded-dev` from the ubuntu repositories.  You will need to configure and build the threaded version from source (hence the dev kit).  Again some basic extensions are not thread safe and can't be used.

> is there a difference in execution times between the thread safe and non thread safe PHP/Apache versions?

Yes some, but if you are that interested in performance then you should by looking at lighttpd, or other alternatives.

> How to install PHP 5.3.10 on Ubuntu

10.04-3 LTS supports  5.3.2.  Precise Pangolin will support PHP 5.3.10, but this is still in development.  You can try building this source set on your current version, but at your own risk.